# ScheduledExecutorService stops a scheduled runnable task and then reruns fine after some time

Tags: dropwizard, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a DropWizard application where we are using Managed Objects(https://www.dropwizard.io/0.6.2/manual/core.html#managed-objects) capability provided by DropWizard. We have used ScheduledExecutorService to scheduled a Runnable from the class which implements Manage which runs very much fine in the time intervals specified(90 mins) but abruptly stops after some runs(there is no particular number to it) and then after some time gets re-triggered again and starts functioning normally. 
I have seen that there are no exceptions happening in between so that the run would stop and not do the runnable task that it is supposed to do. 
Has anyone encountered this issue earlier and can help with the issue.

Here is how we are scheduling it.

```
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, 1, 90, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: How long does your runnable run?

Comment: Not much time. On an average 10 mins.

Comment: It might be a timing issue? I would monitor my runnable and see when it starts/stops.